# Opening a link and trigger modal box on target page?

Tags: html

our customer ordered a simple html one pager website.

the imprint and data protection contents are in the main HTML file and are shown in a modal box.

the modal box is hidden by default and pops up when you click imprint/dataprotection buttons in the footer.

now the customer needed another page and wants to link the imprint and dataprotection there too, but i cant say "open link AND then open modal", right?

is there a possibility to achieve this which i am overlooking?

Comment: If I'm correct you can change the code on the page with the modal, right? And is that a bootstrap modal or something? Can you share the code of the modal with us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have a solution to your problem.
Suppose `main.html` holds the imprint, data protection and here the modal shows up with the function `showModal()` (For example).
`ohter.html` then holds the some simple info.

You can "call" the function `showModal` on `main.html` by passing a hash (`#`) with the url and then checking on `main.html` if that hash is available and then call the function.

It would look something like this:

#### other.html

```html
some html content...
<a href="/main.html#showModal">See your info</a>
...
```

#### main.html

```html
<script>
window.onload = function() {
   if(window.location.hash == "#showModal") {
      showModal();
   }
}
</script>
```

Hope this gives you an idea of how you could implement such behaviour. If this wasn't of help, please comment.

Comment: worked like a charme, very nice! thank you my friend, this fixed some weird problems we would have had if we had to implement another solution :)